# Moving string positions in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to ask you if you know how to move string positions in array. I would like to implement something like this.

If a=1

```
1 2 0 0 0 0
```

if a=2

```
0 0 1 2 0 0
```

if a=3

```
0 0 0 0 1 2
```

I do not have code until now I just want some thoughts.

Comment: **"where can I find examples"**... Soliciting lists of links isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Also google would give you good swap algorithms for any type.

Comment: what does the 'a' represent for? Can this happend when `a==1.5` and the string is `0 1 2 0 0 0`?or you just see the array[0] and array[1] as a whole?

Comment: "jfgi" comments are not helpful unless you help write better google queries. To the OP, good keywords are "array rotate" http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/ Unless you're not rotating but shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
void rotate_right(char *str, size_t n){
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char temp[n %= len];
    memcpy(temp, str + len - n, n);
    memmove(str + n, str, len - n);
    memcpy(str, temp, n);
}
*/

void rotate_right1(char *str){
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char temp = str[len-1];
    memmove(str + 1, str, len - 1);
    str[0] = temp;
}

void rotate_right(char *str, size_t n){
    while(n--)
        rotate_right1(str);
}

int main(void){
    char data[] = "120000";
    char wk[sizeof(data)];
    int a;
    for(a=1;a<=3;++a){
        strcpy(wk, data);
        rotate_right(wk, 2*(a-1));
        printf("%s\n", wk);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: yes I wanted something like that. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm joining the question  - is this a shift or a rotation? if shift you should run the array from the end to the beginning copying cells which are at a position difference of a from the current one. 
Something like:

```
for (i=N;i>=a;i--)
{
array[i]=array[i-a];
}
```

if it's circular you should find a way to update the needed position such as if i-a is smaller then 0 then N-a or something similar.